# Unable to set onItemClickListener in listview

Tags: android

My layout code is as shown below:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/relRingtone"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
> 
            <ListView
               android:focusable="false"
             android:id="@+id/list_notification"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
             android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
             android:layout_marginLeft="3dip" 
             android:textSize="2dp" />
             <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:paddingBottom="40dp" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Start Working"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Chronometer
                android:id="@+id/chronometer"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/btn1"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Vehicle  Details"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/chronometer"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Take Leave"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

     </RelativeLayout>
```

and below is my java code:

```
list_notification.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        String s[] = new String[] { "Your leave request has been accepted",
                "test notification" };
        ArrayAdapter<String> adpt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, s);
        list_notification.setAdapter(adpt);
        list_notification.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "list item clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });`
```

Comment: Can you post the error the LogCat it's throwing? Or it's an error with the IDE?

Comment: My logcat does not show any error related to listview.

Comment: It's your code compiling? Or It's related to Syntax errors? Are your imports correct?

Comment: You should use the following imports:
`import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;`

And also try to use Class Arguments in your ArrayAdapter, something like this
`ArrayAdapter<T> mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<T>(...);`
Where T it's an Object with it's onString method overriden!

Comment: if you're Logcat doesn't show any error related to listview or its listener, then what happens? because you have implemented this simple listener correctly. does it simply not show the toast or what? try to tell more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is layout, add `android:layout_below="@id/list_notification"`

The ScrollView will not overlay the listview

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_below="@id/list_notification"
        >
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this line in `<ListView>` might be the culprit:

```
android:focusable="false"
```

assuming that your error is simply that clicking the items doesn't do anything.

Your UI might have some other issues...stacking a list view on top of a scroll view is going to create problems when your list is taller than the screen.